# Two problems when using YouTube API: Browser Key not working and username/channel name not working

Tags: ajax, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using this project http://codepen.io/juanv911/pen/gbgjLe to extract Followers/Likes/Subscribers data from YouTube, Facebook, Twitter and other sites, the thing is that I'm having two problems:

First Problem: YouTube channel ID/ User ID not working because it's Alphanumeric?

If I try this random youtube user:

```
var youtube = 'envato';
```

it works.

But if I try this it doesn't:

```
var youtube = 'iz2KM8dASHDBAISDGB'; // FAKE User ID
```

Or this one:

```
var youtube = 'UCiz2KM8dDBN2OlERERWA'; // FAKE Channel ID
```

Those IDs are fake BTW, I wrote it like that just to demonstrate the code, except for the `envato`, that's a real youtube user account.
My channel is brand new, so to create a custom user ID I have to meet some requirements.

Second Problem: YouTube API browser Key doesn't work

If I use this API browser key from the project at Code Pen it works:

```
 key:'AIzaSyDXpwzqSs41Kp9IZj49efV3CSrVxUDAwS0'
```

But if I use my own key that I created a while ago, it won't.

Here is my code:

```
*YouTube API V3*/


var youtube = 'envato';


//YouTube API V3
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername='+youtube,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  type: 'GET',
  data:{
    key:'AIzaSyDXpwzqSs41Kp9IZj49efV3CSrVxUDAwS0'
  },
  success: function(data) {   
    var subscribers = parseInt(data.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount);
    var k = kFormatter(subscribers);
    $('#posts .youtube .count').append(k); 
    getTotal(subscribers); 
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the "forUsername" in your code to "id" if you want to use channel id.

Like this:

```
*YouTube API V3*/


var youtube = 'UCJr72fY4cTaNZv7WPbvjaSw';


//YouTube API V3
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id='+youtube,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  type: 'GET',
  data:{
    key:'AIzaSyDXpwzqSs41Kp9IZj49efV3CSrVxUDAwS0'
  },
  success: function(data) {   
    var subscribers = parseInt(data.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount);
    var k = kFormatter(subscribers);
    $('#posts .youtube .count').append(k); 
    getTotal(subscribers); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem. What about the key not working, any idea? I've already enabled it in the developer panel.

Comment: I used my own key and it worked. Maybe you haven't enabled all the required APIs, also it usually take around 5 minutes for a new key to start working properly .

Comment: I found out what the key problem was. I configured the referrer as shown in the example there, with asterisk and slash, when actually all I had to do was to insert a normal address without the protocol, like site.com